# Progress bar not resetting

Tags: javascript, firebase, recursion, firebase-authentication, countdown

I'm creating a countdown of 10 seconds, and at the end, some functions triggers.

These functions that recall the countdown function to start again. However, when it's called again, the bar is still full, resulting in a loop.

Here's the countdown function.

```
function LoadTime() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(User => {
    if(User) {
        var RemainTime = 10;
        var DownTime = setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - --RemainTime;
            if(RemainTime <= 0)
                clearInterval(DownTime);
            if (RemainTime == 0){
                storewager();
                if (Roulette.bet == 1) {
                    RouOutcome();
                }
                else {
                    LoadTime();
                }
            }
        },1000);
    } else {
        alert("please login");
    }
});
```

}

I want this functions to reset the progress bar each time it's triggered. Been stuck on this for a while, so any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's the tree of the functions.

Page load --> LoadTime --> (end of countdown) --> (Outcome process) --> RouOutcome() --> LoadTime().

Seems to be when LoadTime is triggered when it's already finished once, it seems to run the process multiple times. It may be to do with the alert boxes causing issues for the countdown.

Been stuck on this for hours, so any help is much appreciated.

EDIT 2:
Here's are the relevant functions in the correct order. This is assuming the users picks a bet option, and enters a bet. I'm trying to create roulette. Is it possible that the issue could be with the alerts?

```
function LoadTime() {
Roulette.load = 1;
CoinFlip.load = 0;
document.getElementById().style.visibility = "hidden";
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(User => {
    if(User) {
        console.log("user is logged in");
        Roulette.choice = 0;
        var RemainTime = 15;
        var DownTime = setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 15 - --RemainTime;
            if(RemainTime <= 0)
                clearInterval(DownTime);
            if (RemainTime == 0){
                storewager();
                if (Roulette.bet == 1) {
                    RouOutcome();
                }
                else {
                    LoadTime();

                }
            }
        },1000);
    } else {
        alert("please login");
    }
});
}

function storewager(){
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("coinbet").set(0);
var coinwager = document.getElementById("coininput").value;
if (coinwager > 0) {
    Roulette.bet = 1;
    var balref = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("coinbet");
    firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("coinbet").set(coinwager);
    var coinref = firebase.database().ref();
    coinref.child("coinbet").set(coinwager);
    BalVer();
}
else {
    alert("No bet was placed");
    Roulette.bet = 0;
    LoadTime();
}
}

function BalVer(){
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID);
dbRoot.once("value", snap => {
    var cData = snap.val();
    var cBet = cData.coinbet;
    var uBal = cData.userbalance;
    var BalUp = uBal-cBet;
    if (BalUp < 0) {
        alert("You do not have enough balance")
        var BetWipe = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("coinbet").set(0);
    }
    else {
        changeuserbal();
    }

});
}

function changeuserbal(coinwager){
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID);
dbRoot.once("value", snap => {
    var cData = snap.val();
    var cBet = cData.coinbet;
    var uBal = cData.userbalance;
    var BalUp = uBal-cBet;
    firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("userbalance").set(BalUp);
     if (CoinFlip.load == 1) {
        CoinOutcome();
     }
     else {
         RouOutcome();
     }

});
}

function RouOutcome(UserID) {
var OutCome = 0 + (Math.random() * 10000);
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
if (OutCome <= 10000) {
    if (Roulette.choice == 1) {
        alert("You won");
        var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID);
        dbRoot.once("value", snap => {
            var cData = snap.val();
            var cBet = cData.coinbet;
            var uBal = cData.userbalance;
            var WinBal = cBet * 2 + uBal
            var NewBal = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("userbalance").set(WinBal);
            //UpdateBal();
            Roulette.comp = 1;
            LoadTime();
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("you lost/didn't place bet");
        Roulette.comp = 1;
        LoadTime();
    }
}
else if ((OutCome >= 4738) && (OutCome <=9474)) {
    var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    if (Roulette.choice == 2) {
        alert("You won");
        var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID);
        dbRoot.once("value", snap => {
            var cData = snap.val();
            var cBet = cData.coinbet;
            var uBal = cData.userbalance;
            var WinBal = cBet*2+uBal
            var NewBal = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("userbalance").set(WinBal);
            //UpdateBal();
            LoadTime();
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("you lost/didn't place bet");
        LoadTime();
    }
}
else {
    var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    if (Roulette.choice == 3) {
        alert("You won");

        var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID);
        dbRoot.once("value", snap => {
            var cData = snap.val();
            var cBet = cData.coinbet;
            var uBal = cData.userbalance;
            var WinBal = cBet*14+uBal
            var NewBal = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("userbalance").set(WinBal);
            //UpdateBal();
            LoadTime();
         });
    }
    else {
        alert("you lost/didn't place bet");
        LoadTime();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks very much for your help, if you need any more info please say.

Comment: You should try commenting out some of your inner logic to narrow down your issue. As it is currently, every answer will be a guess. For starter, post the code in `RouOutcome();` as we are not able to subsequent calls to `LoadTime()`

Comment: You also mention "the bar is still full" although, your code only depicts setting the value of a DOM element. If you are using css or a library to depict the `progressBar` element as a progress bar provide the HTML, CSS, and / or library.

Comment: If you are concerned with the `alert()`, change them to `console.log()` and watch the developer console (F12 to open). Otherwise I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I created for you to follow. You don't show you attempt at resetting the bar so this is the best I can do at explaining for now.

```js
var pBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var pText = document.getElementById("progressText");
startTimer();

function startTimer() {
  var downIncrement = 10;

  var DownTime = setInterval(function() {
      var currentValue = pBar.getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
      var newValue = currentValue - downIncrement;

      pBar.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", newValue);
      pBar.style = "width:" + newValue + "%";
      pText.textContent = newValue / 10;
      if (newValue <= 0) {
        console.log("time is up!");
        clearInterval(DownTime);
        var Roulette = storewager();
        if (Roulette.bet == 1) {
          RouOutcome();
        } else {
          LoadTime();
        }
      }
    },
    1000);
}

function storewager() {
  console.log("done with store wager");
  return {
    bet: 1
  };
}

function RouOutcome() {
  console.log("done with RouOutcome");
  // restart progress bar
  LoadTime();
}

function LoadTime() {
  pBar.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 100);
  pBar.style = "width: 100%";
  pText.textContent = "10";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
    <span id="progressText">10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the process to generate the outcome still repeats. It seems to be when LoadTime is re-triggered, it already thinks it's ended the countdown. I'll update my main post to provide more info.

Comment: I updated my sample to be more like your original code. You can alter it as you see fit. when LoadTime is triggered the progress bar will reset for you waiting for startTimer() to be called when you want

Comment: His initial post has a reset in the `LoadTime()` when he runs `var RemainTime = 10;` I believe his issue is in code that has yet to be posted.

Comment: @PhillipThomas Okay, I will update my main post with the relevant code.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr thanks very much, I'll add it in and see if I get anywhere.

Comment: @SubZeroFish I don't see where you are setting `Roulette.choice` it seems like its always 0.  I would suggest cleaning up the code (lots of if, else if, elses). Create functions and try to not repeat yourself. if you refactor it you may even find your own bug. The code as is can be pretty had to find bugs in

Comment: @Andrew Lohr I think they're past attempts of trying to solve the issue. But I'll revise it and let you know shortly. Really appreciate the help btw.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr I made RemainTime a global variable, and then reset it from RouOutcome, so the LoadTime was already have the timer reset when it's run. This seems to of solved the issue. Thanks very much for your help, I wouldn't of spotted this if I didn't revise it like you said.